# Find two fields with the same value within separate arrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
"first_name" : [ 

    ]
```

I have database like above . I want find field first_name and last_name have type = primary . I tried this code but it get all data :

```
 var fieledUsers = {
            'first_name': 1,
            'last_name': 1,

            };
            var matching = {
                'first_name.type' :'primary',
                'last_name.type' :'primary'
            }
            var conditionUsers = {"_id": users_id};
            db.collection('users').aggregate([{$project:fieledUsers},{$match:matching}],function (err, resUsers) {
```

How can I do it . Thank in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always "match" the document that contains both properties by supplying the values to both properties as the query condition. But to get the positional match to **both** you need [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) with aggregate:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "_id": users_id,
    "first_name.type": "primary",
    "last_name.type": "primary"
  }},
  { "$addFields": {
    "first_name": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": {
          "input": "$first_name",
          "as": "el",
          "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.type", "primary" ] }
        }},
        0
      ]
    },
    "last_name": {
      "$arrayElemAt": [
        { "$filter": {
          "input": "$last_name",
          "as": "el",
          "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$el.type", "primary" ] }
        }},
        0
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

The [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) which can be used with a standard query is fine for matching a "single" element in array. But for multiple matches, or as in this case where the matches can be in "different" positions in each array, then then this sort of operation with [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) is required. Also using [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) as example to just extract the single element from the array.

Comment: thank you , it worked . But it get all data in db , I only want get first_name and last_name filed . How can I do it

Comment: @ThanhTùng If you only want those fields then use [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) instead of [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/).

Answer (score 0):

According to MongoDB documentation

```
The $elemMatch operator matches documents that contain an array 
field with at least one element that matches all the specified query 
criteria.
```

As a solution according to above mentioned description please try executing following query in MongoDB shell.

```
db.collection.find({first_name:{$elemMatch:{type:'primary'}}, 
last_name:{$elemMatch:{type:'primary'}}})
```

Comment: That actually isn't what `$elemMatch` is for. Rather it's usage is to match a single element on "multiple conditions", typically as multiple properties. The "query" portion as used by the OP and myself is therefore correct and the most optimal. As also mentioned the problem and therefore the "question" is that the [positional `$` operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) for projection only ever returns the "first position matched". Therefore with "two" arrays, the matched position in one may not be the same position in the other.

Comment: So the question is not about matching the "document", since that part was already done. The question is about. "Matching the array elements". For which you need `$filter` for MongoDB to return the correct response.